# Probability density on manifold

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, manifolds

Suppose $\chi$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold embedded in a $2$-dimensional space and there exists an atlas $\mathcal{A}$ which has only one chart $\phi:\chi\to\mathcal{U}$. Here $\mathcal{U}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. A probability space $(\chi,\mathcal{B}(\chi),\mu)$ is defined on $\chi$, where $\mathcal{B}(\chi)$ is the Borel set on $\chi$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure.

I have three questions

1. Can we say that there exists another atlas which also has only one chart $\psi:\chi\to\mathbb{R}$? Because it is not difficult to find an invertable function $f$ to map $\mathcal{U}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $\phi\circ f:\chi\to\mathbb{R}$ can be the new chart.
2. Can we define a probability density in the original probability space $(\chi,\mathcal{B}(\chi),\mu)$?
3. What is the corresponding probabilistic density function in $\mathcal{U}$ corresponding to the probability measure $\mu$?

Comment: Is $\chi$ assumed to be connected?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, $\chi$ is connected.